# Highcharts - rewrite data from one chart to another

Tags: javascript, highcharts

In my example, the data is generated randomly. After click on button, zoom type should be changed.

```
$(function() {

var chartOptions={  
        chart:{
            zoomType : 'x',
            events : {
                load : function() {
                var series = this.series[0];
                    var chart = this;
                    setInterval(function() {
                        var x = (new Date()).getTime(),
                        y = Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
                        series.addPoint([x, y]);
                        chart.redraw();
                    }, 1000);
                }
            }
        },
        series : [{
            name : 'AAPL',
            data : [null]
        }]
    };

$('#container').highcharts('StockChart', chartOptions); 

$('#button').click(function() {
    var chart1 = $('#container').highcharts();
    //alert(chart1.series[0].yData);
    chartOptions.chart.zoomType = 'y';
    $('#container').highcharts(chartOptions);
});
});
```

After click button, the old chart disappears but the new one is not generated.
Firebug shows `TypeError: e is undefined` and in the line `series.addPoint([x, y]);` shows `series is undefined`.

`chartOptions` is global so in the click handler, one property (zoomType) is changed and the rest should be the same.

`alert(chart1.series[0].yData);` shows the propery y data. So I tried:

```
$('#button').click(function() {
    var chart1 = $('#container').highcharts();
    //alert(chart1.series[0].yData);
    chartOptions.chart.zoomType = 'y';
    var chart2 = $('#container').highcharts(chartOptions);
    chart2.series[0].setData(chart1.series[0].data);
    chart2.redraw();
});
```

Then firebug shows `chart2.series is undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot update zoom type in highcharts, without destroy() chart and create new instance. In other words, you should use

```
chart1.destroy()
```

var chart2 = $('#container').highcharts(chartOptions);

In case when you would like set range on any axis (zoom chart) you can use setExtremes() function   http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#Axis.setExtremes()

When `chartOptions` or chart2.series is undefinded you need to use $.extend({},chartoptions)

```
$('#container').highcharts($.extend({},chartoptions);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, I still don't know how to rewrite data from the first chart to the second. This attempt http://pastebin.com/GnMn0JZc brings many errors. Still `chart2.series is undefinded`, `series is undefinded` and some others. What is strange, even without line number 34, this example should work but it doesn't...